# Identifying phone by an id if UDID not allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a requirement for my app that each user can only register for one account. I.e one account per mobile device. I understand that it is not possible to use UDID anymore to identify a device. Is there any alternative to this? When a user signs up for the first time I want to save some sort of unique ID to the server so if they try and do it again the app won't allow it. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: This is a very problematic requirement. What happens to the poor lad that drops his iphone in the pool and gets a new one. Does he have to buy the app again?

Comment: No, the app is free.

Comment: Then he would still have to re-register.

Comment: You can not and should not do this. What if the users sells it phone, the new owner can then nog register. Also Apple has made it near impossible to get any device specific identifier and they have also added to their privacy agreement that this is no longer allowed. You only option is to register the install in the `KeyChain`. This way you can check whether or not the app has been installed before.

Comment: The keychain sounds perfect actually. Just looking at it now. Values will only be deleted if the device does a hard reset right? Are apple okay with using it? It won't get rejected during submission if I use it?

Comment: Yes, the keychain will persist. Only on a hard reset will the value be gone. Apple will not reject you for using the `KeyChain` they might reject your app for the time registration.

Answer (score 1):

Although older UDID is not available, you can still identify the device within the app using [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor).

This uniquely identifies each device for all 'your' (per developer) apps. Read the documentation by apple on the link for ore details.

However, apple discontinued UDID for a reason. You should be tracking users rather than devices. As devices can get lost or broken or replaced as everyone else is saying. So ***i would still suggest reconsidering app design to avoid using device identifiers.*** But after careful thought, if you decide to do it, identifierForVendor is the way to do it.

**EDIT:**

As ponted out by @rckoenes , all your apps will have same vendor identifier. So, to uniquely identify your particular app installed on a device you can use a combination of identifierForVendor and bundle identifier, or a random constant added in the app code, which you can send to the server along with identifierForVendor during login or registration.

**EDIT 2:**

Another important observation by @rckoenes :

> The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

So identifierForVendor will suffice, only if you are satisfied with uniquely identifying a user/device combination per app install and as suggested by apple:

> if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

Comment: Well it is suggested you use the `identifierForVendor` to replace the UDID, it is not unique per device. If you remove al the app from the same verdor and reinstall them you **will** get a new vendor identifier.

Comment: From the documentation by apple: "The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device."

Comment: Down voted because if you use identifierForVendor inappropriately -- that is, not in association with advertising -- Apple will, by their own explicit declaration, reject the app. This should NOT be suggested as a solution for general device identification for app store apps.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke as long a are app installed from the same vender the `identifierForVendor` will stay the same. As clearly stated in the documentation: `The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device.`

Comment: The documentation clearly says "An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor.". @BradBrighton can you please site the source for rejection by apple for using identifierForVendor alone?

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke Yes and it also clearly states: "The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device." So it will only stay the same if an app(s) are installed on the device.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke Every time you submit an app, you get asked if you're using the advertising identifier as part of the iTunes Connect submission process and it says it there, but I don't currently have a screenshot of it. I'll look to see if the Review Guidelines say it as well...

Comment: @rckoenes i agree with your point .. my subsequent comment was for @ BradBrighton 's rejection comment.

Comment: @BradBrighton `identifierForVendor` is not the `advertising identifier`

Comment: Aw crap. Sorry, @SwapnilLuktuke. This still isn't the answer for the OP, but reversed my vote since the reasons were inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

**Apple has come up with the DeviceCheck framework**

Using DeviceCheck API’s, in combination with a server-to-server APIs, a developer can set and query two bits of data per device. It will also maintain user privacy, by not disclosing any user or device information.

Go through [this video from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/702/) for more information. If you are running out of time, watch the video from 24 min.

Answer (score -3):

You should use `advertisingIdentifier` provided by `ASIdentifierManager`

> An alphanumeric string unique to each device, used only for serving
>   advertisements. (read-only)
>
> Unlike the `identifierForVendor` property of the `UIDevice`, the same value is returned to all vendors. This identifier may change—for example, if the user erases the device—so you should not cache it.

Also, you can use `identifierForVendor` provided by `UIDevice` but the value change for each vendors.

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

It depends of what you want to do as @FilipRadelic said. The advertisingIdentifier should only use for advertisement feature

Since iOS5, it's forbidden to get an Unique Identifier per device, so you should user this id

Comment: This is not only incorrect, but will result in App Store rejection when used for something other than advertisement.

Comment: @FilipRadelic Yes, I've changed my answer. ;) but it was written `used only for serving advertisements.`